Using UXSE chat to address concerns about use of AI generated content
There have been a number of people raising concerns about a number of answers that have been provided that is playing out across the comments section of the questions.
The issue is a little bit complicated since it involves both the use of AI generated content, and the potential conflict of interest overlapping with potential self-promotion.
I have created a chat room (remember these?) to give users a safe space to air their concerns and discuss matters with some moderator involvement, and hopefully this will help us work through the issue. The link is here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155182/uxse-ai-discussion
But I am open to other ways that we think this can be addressed.
